# ¿Cómo actualizo un PHP ECHO sin recargar la pagina entera?

Tags: php, html

Tengo un php echo, que suelta un valor sacado de un database, querría actualizarlo para que me muestre el dato actualizado cada X segundos

El echo:

```
<center>
<za>We have served </za><zb><span id="tolurl"><?php echo $total_urls;?></span></zb><za> urls.</za>
</center>
```

Los `<za>` y `<zb>` son argumentos para darle estilo CSS

Comment: ¿`za` y `zb` existen realmente o estás inventando Tu Propio HTML (TPHTML)? Los estilos CSS se aplican a las clases, identificadores, etc. Ejemplo: `<div class="za">We have served </div><div class="zb"><span id="tolurl">...</div>`. En cuanto a tu pregunta, puedes hacerlo con Ajax, el cual sirve para traer información desde el servidor y presentarla en la página actual sin tener que refrescar la página. Aquí mismo hay varias preguntas con explicaciones detalladas de cómo se hace.

Comment: Sí. los creo yo, porque con los div me crea un bloque y para mí, los puedo modificar mejor si los creo como si fuera un `<p>`

Comment: Cuestiónate el hecho de usar TPHTML... te podría dar problemas. HTML tiene elementos para todo. Por ejemplo tiene un elemento llamado `<p>`. En vez de inventarte un `<za>`, puedes usar `<p class="za">...</p>` y por CSS: `.za { //estilos que quieres aplicar }`. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Ah, ¿entonces es lo mismo `<za>`, que escribir `<p class="za">`, (en cuanto a CSS) ?

Comment: No, no es lo mismo. `<p class="za">` **es mejor** que `<za>`. Ya que esto último no es un estándar, sino algo que tú te has inventado y ni siquiera se sabe si va a funcionar. Y aunque funcione, nadie va a entender lo que intentas hacer con eso... y cuando alguien vea el código CSS en el cual intentas darle estilo tampoco lo entenderá (si es que funciona). Lo que quiero decir es que HTML cuenta con todo tipo de elementos para cualquier uso, no tienes que inventar nada, lo que tienes es que **usar el elemento adecuado** y asignarle las clases que quieras para modificar su estilo por CSS.

Comment: Si funciona en casi cualquier plataforma, pero he probado algunas donde no apareze texto porque no entenderá el codigo, bueno entonces solo cambio los `<za>` por `<p class="za">` y no tendré que cambiar el css?

Comment: Si tú pones algo así: `<p class="za">Texto que estaba dentro de mi etiqueta za</p>` y luego en CSS pones esto por ejemplo: `.za {color:red;}` la regla se aplicará a ese elemento porque tiene la clase `za`. Y así, cualquier estilo que pongas entre los `{...}` se aplicará a ese elemento y a cualquier otro que tenga la clase `za`... Así te mantienes dentro del estándar HTML y CSS sin tener que inventar nada. Puedes hacer la prueba.

Comment: He probado y no funciona, tendría que cambiar el css a `p.za { // argumentos }`

Comment: Quizá no funciona porque está dentro de una etiqueta `<center>`, la cual por cierto es obsoleta, si mal no recuerdo. En vez de `<center>`, tú puedes usar un `div` que encierre todo el bloque y centrar lo que haya dentro de ese `div`. En CSS los elementos se alcanzan según los contenedores en los que se encuentren. Y si quieres alcanzarlos directamente puedes ponerle una etiqueta `id`. Por ejemplo si tú le pones esto: `<p id="za">Texto que estaba dentro de mi etiqueta za</p>` y en el CSS pones: `#za {color: red;}`, ahí lo alcanzas seguro. Convendría que leas un poco sobre CSS...

Comment: ...si te inventas las cosas y usas etiquetas obsoletas, vas a escribir un código que a la larga se hará incomprensible incluso para ti mismo y casi imposible de mantener y de depurar. Y será un código que quizá ni siquiera funcione en algunos escenarios.

Comment: Los he envuelto en un div y he quitado los center, y el div está centrado, pero ahora sigue pasando que pide un `p.za`y no adopta el estilo del `za`

Comment: Como te decía, en CSS los elementos se alcanzan según las etiquetas que tengan y las prioridades de esas etiquetas. Por ejemplo, la etiqueta `id` tiene más prioridad que la etiqueta `class`. Si un elemento marcado por `class` está dentro de uno o varios `div` que a su vez tienen otras clases, no vas a poder alcanzarlo poniendo solamente la clase del elemento que están dentro de esos varios `div`, sino que tendrás que irlo buscando entre las clases. Es importante que leas algún tutorial sobre el tema y sobre buenas prácticas en CSS. Hay buenos tutoriales que enseñan a escribir código organizado

Comment: Para cambiar el contenido dinámicamente, puedes usar javascript: $("#tolurl").html("nuevo valor"); y para obtener los datos desde la base de datos, AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

## NO SE PUEDE

Lo siento, lo que pides es impocible, debido a como funciona PHP, paso a explicar:

El archivo PHP se ejecuta a demanda, la demanda es una solicitud enviada por el navegador (hasta aqui en el cliente) a un servidor HTTP que para resolver el HTML necesita ejecutar el PHP, tras la ejecucion del PHP este devuelve un TEXTO PLANO (con formato HTML) que el servidor HTTP le devuelve al cliente que lo solisitó, el navegador toma ese texto plano con formato HTML y lo procesa, convirtiendoce asi en objetos (DOM) HTML (ya sea el label donde lees esto, o el cuadro de texto donde responderas).

## PERO

Pero, para brindar dinamismo a los datos ya existentes, el navegador pocee un intérprete de JavaScript (normalmente, ademas de otros), éste brinda la pocibilidad de funciones ejecutadas EN EL CLIENTE, que por ejemplo desactiven un boton si un check box no esta marcado.

Sin embargo, y gracias a estas funciones corriendo en el cliente, pueden enviarce solicitudes HTTP internas e "independientes" a la carga de la pagina o a las interacciones del usuario. Una de las principales tecnologias basadas en este concepto es [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), que corresponde a una solicitud desde el propio JavaScript, "trasparente" al usuario y que se suele utilizar para capturar eventos que suseden del lado del servidor como notificaciones, o cargar nuevo contenido al ya existente el la propia pagina o producto de una accion del usuario o de un bucle de constantes llamadas a esa funcion.

En este punto entiendes que es necesario que "otro" php (o lo que sea) genere el dato que cargarás ahí gracias a ejecutar el ajax dento de tu JavaScript

El bucle para las llamadas a la actualizacion de ese campo es facilmente realizables con un [TimeOut](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) Dentro de una funcion que se llame a si misma.

Tambien a todo esto hay que aclarar que hay una simplificacion del uso de AJAX en [JQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp), esta libreria deberás cargarla al JavaScript (Es un `.js`)

## O TAMBIEN

Por otro lado, el metodo mas precario, utilizado antes de la existencia del ajax, es el [Iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), que consiste en un objeto "Navegador" dentro de los objetos de la pagina, este pocee su propio motor JavaScript, y por lo tanto un `setTimeout(location.reload(),3000)` (u otra de las [535 maneras de recargar la pagina](http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html)) dentro de una etiqueta "Script" en la pagina cargada por el Iframe, solo recargará el Iframe.

Comment: Pienso que puede ser posible, he visto paginas, que por ejemplo te van enseñando el total de usuarios o de otro dato, y en la pagina se recarga esa cifra y va aumentando

Comment: @Aspoky Esos "contadores" suelen ser falsos, dado un incremento X con cierto grado de aleatoriedad, puedes hacer la prueva desconectando tu internet, si vez que el contador sigue cambiando, este es falso (dado que no podria actualizarse algo sin conexion, cierto?). Saludos.

Comment: @Aspoky creo que te faltó leer desde el 4to párrafo en adelante, donde después de explicarte que no se puede de la forma que lo estás haciendo, te explica cómo deberías hacerlo con una solicitud AJAX.