# actualizar un echo sin recargar pagina

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-3

buenas tardes comunidad espero que me puedan ayudar tengo un dasboard y quiero actualizar los datos sin tener que refrescar la pagina

**mi vista**

```
 <h3><?php  echo $total_products ?></h3>
```

**controlador**

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("User_model");
        $this->load->model("Project_model");
        $this->load->model("Quotations_model");
        $this->load->model("Client_model");
        $this->load->model("Provider_model");

        

    }


    public function index()
    {
        $this->data['total_user'] = $this->User_model->countTotalUsers();
        $this->data['total_project'] = $this->Project_model->countTotalProject();
        $this->data['total_Quotations'] = $this->Quotations_model->countTotalQuotations();
        $this->data['total_Client'] = $this->Client_model->countTotalClient();
        $this->data['total_Provider'] = $this->Provider_model->countTotalProvider();

        $this->load->view('base_site/head');
        $this->load->view('side/ver');
        $this->load->view('dashboardhome/dashboard', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('base_site/footer');
        $this->load->view('base_site/scripts');
    }

    public function total_productos()
{
    echo $this->User_model->countTotalUsers();  
}
}
```

**modelo**

```
   public function countTotalUsers()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT *FROM usuarios";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

**script**

```
<script>

$.ajax({
          url: 'dashboardhome/Dashboard/total_productos',
          success:  function (response) 
          {
              $("#valor").html(response);                 
          }

     });
</script>
```

ya me muestra la cantidad de datos peor tengo que refrescar la pagina y lo que quiero es hacerlo con script para que cuando registre un usuario lo muestre sin tener que recargar la pagina  espero me puedan ayudar a utilizar script gracias

[intente guarne de](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137600/c%C3%B3mo-actualizo-un-php-echo-sin-recargar-la-pagina-entera)

Comment: Te falta colocar el id al **h3** y si necesitas que se actualize coloca todo dentro de una funcion y la llamas cuando necesites te dejo un ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/sp4frm0e/1/ y llamas a la funcion cuando necesites y listo :)

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo:

1-Coloca un id a tu **h3**

```
<h3 id="valor"><?php  echo $total_products ?></h3>
```

2-Con Jquery Busca para actualizar, te dejo un ejemplo rápido

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'url_buscar_valor.php',
          success:  function (response) 
          {
              $("#valor").html(response);                 
          }

     });
```

Te explico Que tiene el Ajax, url donde buscaras el nuevo valor **carpeta/controlador/funcion**

y dentro de esa funcion imprimes tu valor de productos y el **$("#valor")** lo mostrará en tu h3

---

EDIT:

Crea una función nueva en tu controlador

```
public function total_productos()
{
    echo $this->User_model->countTotalUsers();  
}
```

Accedes desde la url de Ajax

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'tuweb.com/total_productos',
          success:  function (response) 
          {
              $("#valor").html(response);                 
          }

     });
```

y listo, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: no funciona tengo que recargar la pagina

Comment: Pero si tu título dice **actualizar un echo sin recargar pagina**

Comment: si eso quiero hacer pero creo que no estoy segura  que debo de poner en la url  a la funcion a cual seria

Comment: La url del ejemplo debe ser con una funcion nueva en tu controlador.. ya te dejo un edit en mi respuesta

Comment: $.ajax({
          url: 'url_buscar_valor.php',
          success:  function (response) 
          {
              $("#valor").html(response);                 
          }

     });   yo lo puse en mi script tengo un archivo con ese nombre

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta para que entiendas lo que te digo

Comment: yo no tengo una funcion por que lo mando desde el index pero de mandarlo asi me manda toso y distorciona el cuadro edito lo que publique

Comment: El **index** que nombras es una funcion ;) solo copias la funcion que te envie, la colocas en tu controlador y con JS actualizas

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente podes hacer un GET por ajax y manejar algun evento que permita la carga:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '{{ route("actualizar-datos") }}',
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(response) {
     $('#input-o-div').html(response);
   },
   error: function (xhr, status, error) {
     console.error(error);
   }
```

Mejor seria hacer un event broadcasting usan webSocket. "Laravel Echo" que se integra a "Pusher" en eventos en tiempo real. Es un poco mas complejo pero eso ya queda a criterio de tu requerimiento y necesidad.